# why to use volley or picasso

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso

Well, so far I have noticed that two options for a real app that wants to show a photo gallery composed of images that exist on a server are: **volley** and **picasso**. There are many useful tutorials about them like [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/) available on Internet. But, my problem is that why should I use them at all? Is anything wrong with just using the URLs of the images in our `ImageView`s?

Edit: in compliance with CommonsWare's comment my question is that why we don't simply use ImageView.setImageURI or methods like that?

Comment: Because of the reasons in the article you link to?

Comment: If you tried it you would quickly realize why

Comment: Oh I'm really wondering why aren't you instructors at MIT?! is this an answer?

Comment: @DaveNewton It compares them, but doesn't say what happens if you don't use any of them at all! read it carefully!

Comment: If you want people to draw comparisons between X and Y, you need to *completely describe* X and Y. What, exactly, do you mean by "just using the URLs of the images in our ImageViews"?

Comment: @mok: "is this an answer?". no. they're comments. answers are below :P

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean you can use and ImageView and pass the url of the image as its src field.

Comment: The [`android:src` attribute on an `<ImageView>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src) takes a drawable resource reference (or, oddly, a color), not a URL. So, let's try again: What, exactly, do you mean by "just using the URLs of the images in our ImageViews"?

Comment: @CommonsWare Indeed I have never developed a commercial app with huge demands so I've not ever recognized the necessity of these tools.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oops, seems I'm too noob. I thought I can pass the url directly to it!

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, sorry I mean ImageView.setImageURI

Comment: @mok It *explicitly* states the problems the libraries solve that you have to implement by hand if you don't use the libraries.

Comment: @DaveNewton See, sometimes you know about something so you understand some notes that a beginner doesn't ever notice. After reading the two answers below I got the main point in using these libraries, and I'm reading the article again. Please put yourself in the OP's shoes.

Comment: @mok YMMV, but: Last sentence, first paragraph. First sentence, third paragraph. Last paragraph before Picasso intro. Pros and Cons of Picasso section. last two sentences of Volley intro, paragraph two. Pros and Cons of Volley. I mean, the first three paragraphs sum up the problem and solutions. The summaries of each library discusses in further detail. I'm not sure how it could get much clearer than that if your question is, as stated in the OP, "Why should I use them at all?" *shrug*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no means of directly handing a URL to an `ImageView`. The closest thing is `setImageURI()`, and that has three problems:

1. I don't think it handles HTTP at all
2. Even if it did, as the docs for that method indicate, it does so on the main application thread, causing you to crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`
3. Even if you use some script-kiddie approaches to block that exception, your UI will be frozen while the download is proceeding

The #1 reason to use [an image loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) is to get the image loading work done on background threads, updating the `ImageView` (or `NetworkImageView` in Volley's case) when the image is ready. Many of these libraries offer additional useful features, outlined in the blog post that you linked to and in other answers here.

Comment: Comprehensive as always. Indeed I was looking for the main reasons. I already knew they(especially picasso in this case ) provide you with some other utilities.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used volley, but I have used picasso. Some of the benefits over raw the URLs include:

- automatic resampling of the raw image data to fit the area you need (saves RAM)
- automatic cancel of the download/render if your views are recycled, like when a ListView scrolls out of view
- local caching of images, so they don't need to be re-downloaded all the time
- allows you to set up callbacks when the image fails to load and/or loads successfully
- probably more than that that just aren't coming to mind at the moment

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean it gives you the ability to retry if it fails to download an image?

Comment: If I recall, number of retries can be configured much easier than using a callback. One of the things I use the callback for is to toss some default image in there from the assets folder if picasso fails to load the networked one. Which reminds me, picasso can also load images from the assets folder (I don't know if native URLs can do that - never tried)